# Installing a 3rd party module for Qt 5.5 in OSX

Tags: c++, qt, terminal

I want to install [Qt Xlsx](http://qtxlsx.debao.me) 3rd party module to use with QtCreator on a OSX system. I tried the [instructions](http://qtxlsx.debao.me/building.html) provided by the official page but I am failing to compile the code.

What I tried,

- My Qt project is on directory: `/Users/Documents/Qt Projects/Test`
  So as instructed in the guide, I copy pasted the source code from gitHub to this directory.
- Then I navigated to this working directory through `Terminal` and executed the following code;
   `qmake
   make
   make install`
  But when I run this code (at command `qmake`, the terminal returns the following error;
  `-bash: qmake: command not found`

Since this method failed, I tried the second method listed on the guide. But I do not understand second point of this given method. The guide says;

> 2. Put the source code in any directory you like. For example, 3rdparty:
>           `|-- project.pro
>      |-- ....
>      |-- 3rdparty\
>      |     |-- qtxlsx\
>      |     |`

And also the 3rd point which reads;

> 3. Add following line to your qmake project file:
>      `include(3rdparty/qtxlsx/src/xlsx/qtxlsx.pri)`

What is the `qmake` project file? Is it the `Test.pro` file in my working directory? How do I install this module? Please explain clearly since I do not have much experience with Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So made it work;
According to the QtXlsx [documentation](http://qtxlsx.debao.me/building.html) 
I just have to add the following lines to my `.pro` file.

> `include(3rdparty/qtxlsx/src/xlsx/qtxlsx.pri)`
>   
>   `XLSX_NO_LIB`

So the directory of your project should look something like this;

> `<project folder>/3rdparty/qtxlsx`